# Building WebRTC in multithreaded DLL on Windows

Tags: webrtc, ninja, gn

Straight question about WebRTC compilation on Windows (GN/Ninja): Is there a specific configuration in GN that tells ninja to build WebRTC into DLLs that can be consumed by a MSVC application? Currently I just build them statically, but this is not good because I am using a legacy application that should consume WebRTC in dynamic link only. Looking into WebRTC build list (in gn) it seems there is no such configuration. Is that statement correct? If not, what would be the option to be used?